# Stopping Thread B when Thread A Stops

Tags: java, multithreading, swt

I have a operation listener that starts and runs Thread A.  When the operation completes Thread A stops and the Dialog Window Closes.

I have created a simple progress bar that is UNKNOWN.  Mainly, because there is no way to get a average operation time.  The time is based on varying factors.  So, I set the TOTAL_TIME fairly high.

I would like to some-how stop the Progress Bar Thread right before the Dialog closes.

**ProgressBarThread**

```
 class ProgressBarThread implements IRunnableWithProgress {
  private static final int TOTAL_TIME = 5000;
  private static final int INCREMENT = 1000;

  public ProgressBarThread() {

  }

  public void run(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws InvocationTargetException,InterruptedException {
     monitor.beginTask("Sending Plot", IProgressMonitor.UNKNOWN);
     for (int total = 0; total < TOTAL_TIME ; total += INCREMENT) {
        Thread.sleep(INCREMENT);
        monitor.worked(INCREMENT);
        if (total == TOTAL_TIME / 2) monitor.subTask("Please be patient... Operation should finish soon.");
    }
    monitor.done();

  }
```

**OperationListener - Closes the window when the operation returns**

```
 public abstract class MyOperationListener implements InterfaceAIFOperationListener {

  AplotPlotterDialog w = null;

  public MyOperationListener(AplotPlotterDialog win) {
     w = win;
  } 

  public void startOperation(String startMessage) {
     Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           w.getShell().setCursor(new Cursor(Display.getCurrent(), SWT.CURSOR_WAIT));
           w.recursiveSetEnabled(getShell(), getShell().getEnabled());
           w.getShell().setEnabled(!getShell().getEnabled());
        }
     });
  } 

  public void endOperation() {
     try {
        endOperationImpl();
     }
     finally {
        Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
              w.getShell().setCursor(new Cursor(Display.getCurrent(), SWT.CURSOR_ARROW));
              w.recursiveSetEnabled(getShell(), true);
              w.getShell().setEnabled(!getShell().getEnabled());
              w.close();
           }
        });
     }
  } 
  abstract protected void endOperationImpl();
```

}

**Method to start the ProgressBar**

```
  public void startProgressBar() {
  try {
     new ProgressMonitorDialog(getShell()).run(true, false,
        new ProgressBarThread());
  } 
  catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
     MessageDialog.openError(getShell(), "Error", e.getMessage());
  }  
  catch (InterruptedException e) {
     MessageDialog.openInformation(getShell(), "Cancelled", e.getMessage());
  }
```

}

**Operation Method and Where ProgressBar starts**

```
 public void startPrintOperation() {
  Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
        startProgressBar();
     }
  });
  final ArrayList<PlotData> datasetData =  AplotPlotDataModel.getInstance().getPlotDataArray();
  plotOp = new AplotPlotOperation(appReg.getString("aplot.message.PLOTTING"),datasetData, getPlottersData(), getSpinnerValue(), session);
  plotOp.addOperationListener(new MyOperationListener(this) {
     public void endOperationImpl() {
        try {
           plotResults = (ArrayList) plotOp.getPlotResults();
           for (int i = 0; i < plotResults.size(); ++i) {
                            AplotResultsDataModel.getInstance().addEntry((AplotPlotResultsParser.DatasetPlotResult) plotResults.get(i));
           } // end for
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
           plotOp.removeOperationListener(this);
           plotOp = null;
           Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                 baseDialog.removeAllTableRows();
                 AplotPlotDataModel.getInstance().clearPlotDataArray();
              }
           });
        }
     }
  });
  session.queueOperation(plotOp);
}
```

***------------------------EDIT------------------***

This is how I am tried to implemented the suggestion be @Serious.

Changes made to the ProgressBar Class

```
class ProgressBarThread implements IRunnableWithProgress  {
  private static final int TOTAL_TIME = 10000;
  private static final int INCREMENT = 1000;
  private Condition done = null;

  public ProgressBarThread(Condition done) {
     this.done = done;
  }

  public void run(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws InvocationTargetException,InterruptedException {
     monitor.beginTask("Creating PDF File(s)", IProgressMonitor.UNKNOWN);
     for (int total = 0; total < TOTAL_TIME ; total += INCREMENT) {
        if (done.await(INCREMENT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
        {
           break;
        }
        monitor.worked(INCREMENT);
        if (total == TOTAL_TIME / 2) monitor.subTask("Please be patient... Operation should finish soon.");
     }
    monitor.done();
  }
}
```

This is the changes to MyOperationLisnter Class

```
public abstract class MyOperationListener implements InterfaceAIFOperationListener {
  AplotCreatePDFDialog w = null;
  Condition done = null;

  public MyOperationListener(AplotCreatePDFDialog win) {
     w = win;
     Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
     done = lock.newCondition();
  } 

  public void startOperation(String startMessage) {
     Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
     startProgressBar();
        }
     });
  }

  public void startProgressBar() {
     try {
        new ProgressMonitorDialog(getShell()).run(true, false,
        new ProgressBarThread(done));
     } 
     catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        MessageDialog.openError(getShell(), "Error", e.getMessage());
     }  
     catch (InterruptedException e) {
        MessageDialog.openInformation(getShell(), "Cancelled", e.getMessage());
     }
  }

  public void endOperation() {
     try {
        endOperationImpl();
     }
     finally {
        Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
              w.getShell().setCursor(new Cursor(Display.getCurrent(), SWT.CURSOR_ARROW));
              w.recursiveSetEnabled(getShell(), true);
              w.getShell().setEnabled(!getShell().getEnabled());
              done.signal();
              w.close();
           }
        });
     }
  } 
  abstract protected void endOperationImpl();
}
```

I remove the startProgressBar method from the Dialiog Class.
I also removed the startProgressBar from the Method that starts the Operation Listener

```
 private void startSavePdfOperation() {
  //Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
  //   public void run() {
  //      startProgressBar();
   //  }
  //});
  saveOp = new AplotSaveOperation(appReg.getString("aplot.message.SAVETOPDF"), "PDF", session);
  saveOp.addOperationListener(new MyOperationListener(this) {<-- this is the start operation listener call.
```

Results:  I get a error dialog instead of the ProgressBar Dialog.  I also get the following error

[image]

and the application freezes.

Comment: The usual way to stop a progress bar is for the progress bar to expose a variable that is modified by the other thread and the progress bar loop exits if its value has changed.

Answer (score 0):

You could wait for a **condition** :

```
class ProgressBarThread implements IRunnableWithProgress
{
    private static final int TOTAL_TIME = 5000;
    private static final int INCREMENT = 1000;

    private Condition done = null;

    public ProgressBarThread(Condition done)
    {
        this.done = done;
    }

    public void run(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws InvocationTargetException,InterruptedException
    {
        monitor.beginTask("Sending Plot", IProgressMonitor.UNKNOWN);
        for (int total = 0; total < TOTAL_TIME ; total += INCREMENT)
        {
            if (done.await(INCREMENT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
            {
                break;
            }
            monitor.worked(INCREMENT);
            if (total == TOTAL_TIME / 2) monitor.subTask("Please be patient... Operation should finish soon.");
        }
        monitor.done();
    }
}
```

The condition is created by the main process :

```
AplotPlotterDialog w = null;

Condition done = null;

public MyOperationListener(AplotPlotterDialog win)
{
    w = win;
    Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    done = lock.newCondition();
} 

public void startProgressBar()
{
    try
    {
        new ProgressMonitorDialog(getShell()).run(true, false,
        new ProgressBarThread(done));
    } 
    catch (InvocationTargetException e)
    {
        MessageDialog.openError(getShell(), "Error", e.getMessage());
    }  
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        MessageDialog.openInformation(getShell(), "Cancelled", e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void endOperation()
{
    try
    {
        endOperationImpl();
    }
    finally
    {
        Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        w.getShell().setCursor(new Cursor(Display.getCurrent(), SWT.CURSOR_ARROW));
        w.recursiveSetEnabled(getShell(), true);
        w.getShell().setEnabled(!getShell().getEnabled());
        done.signal();
        w.close();
    }
    });
    }
}
```

While the operation is in progress the behavior will be the same as your current version.

But when the main process is done it will notify, by signaling the condition, the progress-bar thread which will exit the loop immediately.

Comment: MyOperationListener has to have the method StarOperation - You replaced it with StartProgressBar.  Should I do something like startOperation() { startProgressBar }?

Comment: I really like the idea of the Condition.  Please see my edit above and see where I am having a problem.  Thanks